# Android WebView: is there a way, in javascript, to load another javascript file and preserve filename/line number information for stack traces?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, stack-trace

I've got a WebView.  It's got some javascript.  I need to dynamically and synchronously load more javascript stored in the assets folder.

eval() works just fine when I pull in the code from the asset by hand and pass it as a string.

The problem is that stack traces aren't useful for code that was pulled in with a string eval.  You just get "eval at  (file:///android_asset/..."

Is there another way to dynamically pull in javascript code, from javascript, that would make stack traces useful?

(FYI, I'm just using WebView as a javascript engine so I can use lots of our existing cross-platform javascript.  It's not displaying any sort of useful HTML.)

Edit:

You can add this:

```
/@ sourceURL=snarkloading.js
```

To the string that gets evaled, and you'll get *snarkloading.js* as the name of the file.

Comment: Just embed it through your javascript as a new `<script>` element and the browser will properly add the new scripts. And no, don't fetch the contents, just use the `src` parameter and link to the .js file.

Comment: Your answer is useful, but I edited and added a critical word - "synchronously".  (And there's no UI here; no one cares if the code stalls waiting for IO for a second.  That's fine.)

Comment: I hope you realize that it won't just be the code that stalls, the whole page will be unresponsive. If that's okay, then synchronously will work.

Comment: There is no UI, and there's no page to be unresponsive.  We're using javascript as a regular programming language, not to manipulate UI elements.  (OK, we're using a hidden WebView, so there is a page, but no one cares.  If I could get a javascript engine without a UI, I'd do it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can load scripts like this...

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
script.onload = function () {
    // Do your thing when script is loaded
    alert('script loaded'); 
}; 
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

Write your code in the onload event handler. This is when the code is actually downloaded and available.

**Update**
There is a way to download scripts synchronously. I remember using the jQuery Ajax function for this with the following option.

> **async** (Boolean)
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false is deprecated.

You can read more about this on the [jQuery API documentation for Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax). The documentation states that it is deprecated in as jQuery 1.8. But if you can get your hands on an older version you can use that one or figure out how they did it.

Comment: Works, thanks.  One other thing is that we assign the result of our eval of the file to an object ; do you know if there's any way to get that from the script element?  (I didn't see anything in the doc for HTMLScriptElement that looked like it would help)

Comment: Sadly enough you need to assign it to global variable and get it from there. Otherwise you need to download your script as text and eval it in the scope of a function and assign it to a local variable.

Comment: One note is that this is asynchronous, so it's going to be a bit more challenging to implement in my setup.  (By "more challenging", I think I mean impossible, but I'm still thinking about it.)

Comment: I always recommend to think async in JavaScript. You don't want to block the main thread otherwise your app or site freezes completely. So design for async from the getgo.

Comment: That doesn't always make sense.  Remember that javascript is just a language, and sometimes it's deployed in non-user-facing situations.  It's fine to block if no one is watching.  Also, often you're faced with large quantities of existing code.  You're not going to be able to make architectural changes if you're just one of 27 environments the code runs in.

Comment: @JamesMoore Here is your answer on downloading script synchronously.